# Get values with Multiple checkboxes in Razor MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox

Currently I'm working on MVC4 web application, I need to get values which are selected or not from multiple checkboxes from the web page. Here is my code in View to render checkboxes.

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Controller", "NameSpace", FormMethod.Post))
{          
     @foreach (var Leave in Model)
        {
            <tr class="Row">
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBox("leaves")
                </td>
                <td>@Leave.EmployeeId</td>
                <td>@Leave.EmployeeName</td>
            </tr>
        }    
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Approve"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Reject"/>
}
```

How can I get those checkBox's values in my controller...?

Answer (score 1):

put a name on the check box(es)and you can pull the value on the controller using request

```
@Html.CheckBox("leaves", new { name = "leaves" })
```

then on then controller

```
string selected = Request.Form["leaves"].ToString();
string[] selectedList = selected.split(',');
foreach(var temp in selectedList){
    // do something with the result
}
```

this will return a comma delimited list (1,5,8) of the id's of all of the selected checkboxes (if there are more than 1).

Comment: I added some more code to my answer.  If you are having issues, let me know where and ill try to help.

Comment: I dont think only a part of your form body should be post as view model. Add a property to your view model and use editorFor<> or checkboxFor.

Answer (score 0):

You better use:

```
string[] selectedList =Request.Form.GetValues("leaves");
```

Instead of:

```
string selected = Request.Form["leaves"].ToString();
string[] selectedList = selected.split(',');
```

for getting an array instead of one concatenated string which needed to be splitted.

Moreover, in this way you don't have to worry about having  commas in your values.